# what to do after deploying laravel project?

Tags: laravel, deployment, hosting, shared-hosting

I just uploaded my laravel project to my shared hosting and was wondering what things and changes to configuration should I make to make the project work?

Comment: Are there any errors? Please elaborate what is not working.

Comment: no there aren't any errors I didnt't change anything I want to know the steps to take after uploading the projects so that i don't encounter any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My typical checklist:

- Modify the document root to the /public folder
- Make the `/storage` and `bootstrap/cache` folders writeable.
- Set up the database
- Modify the .env file to suit the live environment
- Run `php artisan migrate`

This should get you up and running, or at least bring you to a point where the errors are detailed enough to work things out